# what does Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D' to 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody' mean (sorry if its a stupid question)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**solution found, check comments on this post for @hijinxbassist's solution**

ok

I'm an idiot when it comes to unity
usually a search on the internet tells me just what I need!

[**nope**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IskGT.png)

so I'm going to ask good ol' stack overflow

[the error is disclosed above and in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6F01.jpg)

[here is the component im trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6F01.jpg)

aaannnddd here is the code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class moveent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject otherGameObject;


    private Rigidbody rigidbody2d;


    void Awake()
    {
        rigidbody2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rigidbody2d.GravityScale = 1;
    }


    void update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            rigidbody2d.GravityScale = 1;

        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            rigidbody2d.GravityScale = -1;
        }

    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: They are different types, and cannot be converted from one to the other implicitly.

Comment: @hijinxbassist, the thing is though... I'm not referring to a rigid body, I'm referring to a rigid body 2d

Comment: `private Rigidbody rigidbody2d;`  You are defining the type as Rigidbody, but then attempt to assign a Rigidbody2D to that variable.

Comment: well plain `Rigidbody` != `Rigidbody2d` .. looks like a typo to me